# Am I misunderstanding the concept of magnetic flux?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, electromagnetic-induction

I have encountered a problem which I should know how to solve because I have studied electromagnetism and did a wide range of problems, but there is something conceptual that is keeping me from understanding. I am going to write the whole problem, I don't want it solved but it's just so you see what I am talking about.

There is a circuit with resistance $R$, a moving bar of lenght $l$ has initial velocity $v= \frac{l}{T}$ and at $t=0$ the bar is in position $x=0$. In the beginning the circuit is in a region where $\vec{B}=0$, the the bar starts moving into a region with a non-zero magnetic field, which varies with time according to the function: $$B(t) = B_{0} \frac{t^2}{T^2}$$
for $0 \leq t \leq T$,
or in another case it may vary as a function of space, as:

$$B(x) = B_{0} \frac{x}{2l}$$for $0 \leq x \leq 2l$.

Here is a drawing of the first situation, are these two cases similar conceptually? How do I get the flux in the first place? Do I need to integrate? Do I need to change variable?

[image]

EDIT: I forgot to add my calculations for the first example

$ \Phi(B) = B_{0}\frac{t^2}{T^2} x(t) l \Longrightarrow f_{i} = -\frac{\Phi(B)}{dt} = -\frac{B_{0}}{T^2} (2tx(t)+t^2v(t))$

Now I have this doubt about calculus: is it correct to write x(t) as v(t)t. This way I would do like this:
$ \Phi(B) = B_{0}\frac{t^2}{T^2} [v(t)t] l \Longrightarrow f_{i} = -\frac{\Phi(B)}{dt} = -\frac{B_{0}}{T^2} (2t^2v(t)+t^2v(t)) = -\frac{B_{0}}{T^2} (3t^2v(t))$

Is this conceptually wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\phi_{B}=\iint \vec{B} \cdot \vec{da}$$

If your surface is changing, as with the moving rod example, the bounds of the integral need to vary with time

Assuming that the B field function exists in all space  and that your chosen surface is flat.

The bounds are

$\int_{y=-a}^{y=a}\int_{x=-c}^{x=|\vec{v}|t} $

Here the surface is increasing linearly as  time goes on, matching the velocity of the rod. I have chosen the height of the loop to be 2a in the y axis. And c is the distance from the left side of the loop to the origin

The bounds depends on your axis, and where the b field "starts" with respect to this axis.

For the first example an easier approach would be to know that this problem reduces to

$$B*[area]$$

The area is a function of x, which is itself a function of time x=vt

For your specific chosen axis
$$B*[height× width]$$
$$B*[height × (c+x(t))]$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was solving it the same way as you said, at least I think so, I got confused because my classmates said they were substituting t in function of x. I am going to add my calculation above. What got me confused is that the electromotive force then is not so simple to compute, I did some tricks but I am not sure they are correct